Using fill in Next.js Image component causes CLS
You are creating a list of images with the Next.js Image component. But when I use it, the CLS score is too high.
On first load, the layout breaks as large images are loaded. As more images are loaded, the layout is correct. How can I fix this?
I don't want to use a background image to solve this problem.
Below is the code I used.
import { Container, Flex, Heading, Image, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import NextImage from "next/image";
import { Weekday, getWebtoons } from "~/libs/api/webtoons";

export default async function Home() {
    const webtoons = await getWebtoons();
    const nowWeekday = new Date().getDay();

    return (
        <Container display="flex">
            <Flex flexBasis="full" gap="2" align="flex-start">
                {Object.entries(
                    Object.groupBy(webtoons, (webtoon) => webtoon.weekday),
                ).map(([weekday, items]) => (
                    <Flex
                        key={weekday}
                        flexBasis="full"
                        direction="column"
                        gap="2"
                        padding="2"
                        background={nowWeekday === +weekday ? "bg.inverted" : "bg"}
                        rounded="md"
                    >
                        <Heading
                            width="full"
                            size="sm"
                            padding="2"
                            color={nowWeekday === +weekday ? "fg.inverted" : "fg"}
                        >
                            {Weekday[+weekday]}
                        </Heading>
                        {items.map((webtoon) => (
                            <Flex key={webtoon.id} direction={"column"}>
                                <Flex
                                    aspectRatio={3 / 4}
                                    position="relative"
                                    // backgroundImage={`url(${webtoon.thumbnail})`}
                                    // backgroundSize="cover"
                                >
                                    <Image rounded="md" asChild>
                                        <NextImage src={webtoon.thumbnail} alt="thumbnail" fill />
                                    </Image>
                                </Flex>
                                <Text
                                    fontSize="lg"
                                    textAlign="center"
                                    lineClamp={1}
                                    color={nowWeekday === +weekday ? "fg.inverted" : "fg"}
                                >
                                    {webtoon.title}
                                </Text>
                            </Flex>
                        ))}
                    </Flex>
                ))}
            </Flex>
        </Container>
    );
}


